# Using the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5, how many 3-digit combinations can you make? Repetitions allowed.

Tags: permutations, combinations

The question is:

Using the numbers $1, 2, 3, 4,$ and $5$, how many $3$-digit combinations can you make? Repetitions are allowed. Thanks!

**Edit:**

I just watched the video [Total 3 Digit Numbers If Repetition allowed & Not allowed - Permutations & Combinations Problems](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dw231YQi9yE). That answered my question.

But now I'd like to add some limitations, i. e.: I don't want more than $2$ repeats per $3$ combo. So, is it correct to say $5$ (any number) $\times\ 5$ (any number) $\times\ 4$ (any number except the first two) = $100$?

Comment: How many choices for first digit? Second digit? Try to work it out, you will get the answer.

Comment: I just watched this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dw231YQi9yE

Comment: There are $5^3$ such combinations possible.

Comment: that answered the question. but now I'd like to add some limitations. 
ie: I don't want more than 2 repeats per 3 combo.
so, is it correct to say 5 (any number) x 5 (any number) x 4 (any number except the first two) = 100 ?

Comment: Add it on the body of the question what you have said in the above comment.

Comment: This event is the complement of the event where there are $3$ repetitions. How many such are there?

Comment: Hi Dbchatt, I don't follow you. is it correct to say 5 (any number) x 5 (any number) x 4 (any number except the first two) = 100 ? Thanks! :)

Comment: You have only considered repitititions in the first and the second places. But there may be repitititions in the first and the third or second and the third places. Right?

Comment: Also you didn't explicitly say that which one you dropped in the third place.

Comment: Can you or someone help by explaining how to determine how many combinations are possible for no more than 2 repeats per combination of 3, when given 5 numbers (1,2,3,4,5) ? I do not presently know the formula.

Comment: For instance, 1-1-5, 1-1-4, 1-4-4, but not 1-1-1 or 4-4-4.

Answer (score 1):

#### Original question

You can choose any of the 5 numbers as your first digit (5 options). For your second digit, you can also choose any of the 5 because repetitions are allowed. This gives $5\cdot5$ possibilities. Add in a third digit, once again choosing from the 5 numbers, and you have $5\cdot5\cdot5$, or 125, possibilities.

#### Question with limitations

Consider two cases. In one case, the first two digits are different. There are $5\cdot4$ possibilities that satisfy this. The third can be any of the 5, so there are $5\cdot4\cdot5=100$ possibilities for the first case.

In the second case, the first two digits are the same. There are $5\cdot1=5$ ways this can occur. In this case, the third digit must be different, giving you only 4 options to chose from. This means the second case has $5\cdot1\cdot4=20$ possibilities. 
Adding together the two cases, there are 120 possibilities.

An alternate way of thinking about the problem with limitations is to work backwards from the problem with no limitations. We have 125 possibilities before introducing limitations. Of those possibilities, there are only 5 that violate the limitations (111, 222, 333, 444, and 555). $125-5=120$, so there are 120 possibilities.

Comment: Thank you, Jacob! I follow you. I think there's a typo in the first case scenario, though: "The third can be any of the 5, so there are 5⋅5⋅5=100 possibilities for the first case." Should this be: "The third can be any of the 5, so there are 5⋅4⋅5=100 possibilities for the first case." ? (changed the 5 to a 4)

Comment: @saturnstroll Yes, thank you :)